# How to install mysql in rails in newer ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to how we can install mysql in rails in newer version ruby installed?

I tried this command below:

```
gem install mysql2
```

But I've got an error below:
[image]

---

I'm using windows 10 home, already installed ruby installer and run some rails app(using sqlite db).

Comment: Share your GemFile & GemFile.lock. Also, have u installed mysql on your machine?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. The latest [Windows version of `mysql2` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions/0.5.3-x64-mingw32) does not support Ruby `2.7` yet. When you want to use that gem then you have to downgrade to Ruby 2.6.x. or switch to another OS.

Comment: @spickermann if use wsl2 would the latest version will work Sir?

Comment: Not answering your question directly but using Docker can solve your problem.

Comment: Try the command it suggests, starting: gem install mysql2 -v

Comment: @AJFaraday I already tried but same result sir.

Answer (score 0):

if you creating new rails application with mysql

**rails new app_name -d mysql**

Comment: try to install MySQL latest version. then try once again